# How do I build a link from variables?

Tags: url

I'm building an entry type's menu, automatically populated with several sections. A route for dynamic menu had to be also created.

**Code**

```
{% set section = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('sectionHandle') %}
{% set entryTypes = section.getEntryTypes() %}

{% for entryType in entryTypes %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ section.handle }}{{ url('types/'~entryType.handle) }}">
            {{ entryType.name|ucfirst }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Output**

- craft.dev/sectionHandle/types/entryType.handle

When I access the link, It gets crazy.

**Output**

- craft.dev/sectionHandle/types/sectionHandle/types/entryType.handle

I was trying everything I know, but Whatever I add in front of `{{url('types/'~entryType.handle) }}`, it gets duplicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are building a custom URL, you shouldn't be using [`url()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/functions#url) here, since it automatically appends your values to the `siteUrl`. Try one of these instead:

`<a href="{{ url(section.handle ~ '/types/' ~ entryType.handle) }}">`

-or-

`<a href="{{ siteUrl ~ section.handle ~ '/types/' ~ entryType.handle }}">`

Comment: Have tried it before. And with the same effect. I keep looking for the root of a problem.

Comment: Well, just after I posted my last comment, I think I've fixed it. I don't know, if it's correct, but it seems to be working. `<a href="{{ url(section.handle ~ '/types/' ~ entryType.handle) }}">{{ entryType.name|ucfirst }}</a>` ?

Comment: That should work! I updated my answer to include your solution and another using `siteUrl`